# Virtual storage system relations

Tags: virtual, storage

A virtual storage system has page size p, block size b, and fixed-length record sizer. What should be the relations between p, b and r to make the most efficient system?

Comment: It is somebody's homework, but I thought it's interesting to share this with SO.

Answer (score 1):

`p` should be a multiple of `b` and `b` should be a multiple of `r` otherwise you end up with under filled pages and blocks but normally they don't end up exactly so

Comment: Yes, this idea is based on Dirichlet's Box Principle, however, is there other relation to make this even more efficient? Like p = b^2?